# Perl issues bash pipe into Java

Tags: java, perl, bash, pipe

I am a Perl beginner. I have this Perl snippet

```
$normal_pileup = "samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY";
$tumor_pileup = "samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX ZZZZZ";

bash -c \"java -jar ttt.jar  <\($normal_pileup\) <\($tumor_pileup\) output
```

They try to issue a system call that pipes input from these commands into a Java program. I couldn't make it work. Can anybody please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Is the line 'bash -c...' part of the perl script? It doesn't look like valid perl to me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call bash directly from Perl. If you use `system`, though, /bin/sh will be called which probably does not support the process substitution.

One of possible workarounds is

```
system qq(echo 'java -jar ttt.jar  <($normal_pileup) <($tumor_pileup) output' | bash);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$normal_pileup = "samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY";
```

will not execute any command but will just store `samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY` as a string. The same for `$tumor_pileup`.

If you want to execute the command use

```
$normal_pileup = `samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY`;
```

`bash` is not a Perl command.

```
`java -jar ttt.jar  ...`
```

You "java" is also most likely wrong

- with `<` you specify where STDIN is read. Is supposed to be a file but in your case you are  specifying the output of a previous command. This will only work if the output of `samtool` is a file name.
- if you want your java program to process the output of another command you will need a pipe

  ```
  mycommand | java
  ```

Summarizing I suppose you want

```
` ( samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY; samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX ZZZZZ ) | java -jar ttt.jar output `
```

Comment: thanks very much for your reply. My intention is to run two bash commands "samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY" and `samtools mpileup -q 1 -f XXXX YYYYY`. their output will be directly piped into java program as two parameters.

Comment: @user1632530 so both will not generate a stream of data but just a string? Could you give us an example output?

Comment: the problem is from usage of varscan. the original url is http://varscan.sourceforge.net/somatic-calling.html